# Python Schedule not working

Tags: python

So i have a script that schedules one time jobs using the Schedule module found here:
    https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Right now, the job is called from another Python script using os.System(), and is fed a JobTime through Sys.argv[2], which typically looks like "13:26".

```
def startJob(jobID):
    #Some Job that runs once
    sys.exit()

def main(jobID, jobTime):
    #startJob(jobID)
    print("Scheduling Scan Job For: %s" % (jobTime))
    schedule.every().day.at(jobTime).do(startJob(jobID))
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

jobID = sys.argv[1]
jobTime = sys.argv[2]

main(jobID, jobTime)
```

For some reason however, the job isnt being scheduled for the specific jobTime and it's starting the job as soon as the script gets called, instead of waiting... Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is

```
schedule.every().day.at(jobTime).do(startJob(jobID))
```

It calls `startJob(jobID)` and passes that as the argument for `do`. Instead, you probably want

```
schedule.every().day.at(jobTime).do(startJob, jobID)
```

The schedule docs says that `startJob` will be called with `jobID` when it's scheduled to do so (instead of at schedule time). Python functions evaluate their arguments first, so you're calling `startJob` before you're even concerned with `do`. [Use the Source Luke!](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py#L267)

Comment: Wow its amazing that something so simple could lead to hours of frustration!!